Which substituent has a higher CIP priority, -NMe2 or -NH3+? Also, -NEtMe and -NMe2H+?

Which substituent has a higher CIP priority, $\ce{-NMe2}$ or $\ce{-NH3+}$? Also, $\ce{-NEtMe}$ and $\ce{-NMe2H+}$? How to rank an ammonium substituent?
Chemdraw shows that -NMe2 has a higher priority than $\ce{-NH3+}$ based on the second closer atoms (C,C) than (H,H,H). I'm not sure whether the positive charge can overweigh the second closer atoms or not.
In second case, Chemdraw shows that $\ce{-NMe2H+}$? has a higher priority than $\ce{-NEtMe}$, the same as I expected which is based on the second closer atoms (C,C,H) and (C,C). I just cannot find the relative description in the IUPAC blue book.

Clearly, bromine has the highest and methyl the lowest priority in both examples. In both structures prioritize the groups attached to nitrogen. In structure 1 the groups are N(H,H,H) and N(C,C,ep)["ep"= electron pair]. One looks for the first tie breaker, Because C>H, the priorities are Br>N(C,C,ep)>N(H,H,H)>H. Structure 1 has the S-configuration.
Similarly, in structure 2, N(C,C,H)>N(C,C,ep) because H>ep. Structure 2 has the R-configuration.

